# Cannot run/deploy application on physical device with com.android.tools.build:gradle version higher than 2.0.0

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm having problem to deploy an application when I update `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to version higher than 2.0.0.

When I've changed it to 2.1.2, the project compiled and was build by gradle, but then nothing happens, like its just ignored.

I'm trying to run the app on `LG Swift L5 Optimus` with `Android 4.0.3`

Here is build.gradle of project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here build.gradle of app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "keddit.com.keddit"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile group: 'io.reactivex', name: 'rxjava', version: '1.1.5'
    compile group: 'io.reactivex', name: 'rxandroid', version: '1.2.0'
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.0.2"
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.3'

    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
    testCompile ('org.jetbrains.spek:spek:1.0.25') {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
    }
}
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.3'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repository.jetbrains.com/all"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: And the problem / error message is what, exactly?

Comment: @cricket_007 There is no error, as I wrote, it simply compiles, builds and thats it. Nothing happens.

Comment: Okay. Compile and building is a step before installation. It doesn't install unless you run the install task

Comment: @cricket_007 Well, the point is, when I have 2.0.0 version and press run button (the green arrow) it run the app or attaches the debugger to it. When I've updated the version it finished, says the app was compiled successful and nothing happens. I've tried to run install task separately and the output was, that it was installed, but I need to attach debugger somehow to the app.